# Protocol Extension: cannot assign to get-only property

Tags: swift, protocol-extension

I am having a bit of an access control conundrum when using structs in place of classes to achieve a more protocol oriented programming approach.

I am receiving different message types over the network, which in their raw form are simply an array of bytes.

So I start with a protocol. **Note how the `rawBytes` is marked only as** `{ get }` **so callers can't directly manipulate the raw bytes:**

```
protocol NetworkDataRequest {
     var rawBytes: [UInt8] { get }
}
```

I'm trying to be thread safe and use all the value type, protocol oriented goodness of Swift, so I now create my different message types using structs instead of classes, and adopt the protocol.

```
struct FileRequest: NetworkDataRequest {
     private(set) var rawBytes: [UInt8]
}

struct ConnectionRequest: NetworkDataRequest {
     private(set) var rawBytes: [UInt8]
}
```

All the different message types share a similar structure for the first 10 bytes, for example:

- byte[0] = permissionsByte
- byte[1] = connectionTypeByte
- etc...

Since I'm using structs I don't have inheritance. But I still need some way to have similar behavior between message types. OK, so I use a protocol extension:

```
 extension NetworkDataRequest {

      var permissionsByte: UInt8 {
          get { return bytes[0] }
          set { bytes[0] = newValue } //<-- Nope!
      }

 }
```

But oops! The `rawBytes` is inaccessible:

```
Cannot assign through subscript: 'rawBytes' is a get-only property
```

Is there any way around this? Otherwise all my structs are going to have a lot of boilerplate code (sucks for me), or I'm going to have to open up the rawBytes (very bad)

```
struct FileRequest: NetworkDataRequest {

     private(set) var rawBytes: [UInt8]

      var permissionsByte: UInt8 {
          get { return bytes[0] }
          set { bytes[0] = newValue }
      }


      var connectionTypeByte: UInt8 {
          get { return bytes[1] }
          set { bytes[1] = newValue } 
      }

      ///etc...

}
```

Comment: `which in their raw form are simply an array of bytes.` No they're not, they're `Data`. Use `Data`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
public protocol NetworkDataRequest {
     var rawBytes: [UInt8] { get }
}

private protocol NetworkDataRequestPrivate: NetworkDataRequest {
     var rawBytes: [UInt8] { get set }
}

extension NetworkDataRequest {
    var permissionsByte: UInt8 {
        get { return rawBytes[0] }
    }
}

extension NetworkDataRequestPrivate {
    var permissionsByte: UInt8 {
        get { return (self as NetworkDataRequest).permissionsByte }
        set { rawBytes[0] = newValue }
    }
}

public struct FileRequest: NetworkDataRequestPrivate {
    fileprivate(set) public var rawBytes: [UInt8]
}

public struct ConnectionRequest: NetworkDataRequestPrivate {
    fileprivate(set) public var rawBytes: [UInt8]
}
```

Comment: Interesting!. The only issue I see with this is that now I'm stuck in a single source file. Some of these request types have huge dictionaries associated with them taking up many lines of code. i.e. when byte[9] = 100 it's "Hello", when byte[9] = 101 it's "Goodbye" etc.

Comment: @MH175 That'll be fixed in Swift 4. `private` will extend access to extensions within the same module https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0169-improve-interaction-between-private-declarations-and-extensions.md

Comment: Within the same source file, not the same module.

Comment: @MartinR Oops, I remembered it wrong. Never mind then :p

Answer (score 0):

If the protocol and the protocol extension is defined in the same file then use the `fileprivate` instead of `private`

`fileprivate` allows code from the same file to access it but outside the file it is inaccessible.

Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html